# Spark-java multithreading vs running individual spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am new with Spark and trying to understand performance difference in below approaches (Spark on hadoop)

Scenario : As per batch processing I have 50 hive queries to run.Some can run parallel and some sequential.

**- First approach**

All of queries can be  stored in a hive table  and I can write a Spark driver to read all queries at once and run all queries in parallel ( with HiveContext) using java multi-threading

- pros: easy to maintain
- Cons: all resources may get occupied and
  performance tuning can be tough for each query.

**- Second approach**

using oozie spark actions run each query individual

- pros:optimization can be done at query level
- cons: tough to maintain.

I couldn't find any document about the first approach that how Spark will process queries internally in first approach.From performance point of view which approach is better ?

The only thing on Spark multithreading I could found is:
 **"within each Spark application, multiple “jobs” (Spark actions) may be running concurrently if they were submitted by different threads"**

Thanks in advance

Comment: why -1 ?? If this question is two basic could you please give some pointers to understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is to run hive queries in parallel with the condition

> Some can run parallel and some sequential

This kinda of workflows are best handled by a DAG processor which **Apache Oozie** is. This approach will be clearner than you managing your queries by code i.e. you will be building your own DAG processor instead of using the one provided by oozie.

Comment: lets assume if I can run all of the queries (queries which takes avg 7-8 min each to complete in hive) in parallel will multithreading be the good choice ?

Comment: yes.. if all queries have to run in parallel without any dependencies with other queries than a parallel execution instead of Dag processor like Oozie would make sense..